# Need for laser handbook with overview of different types of semiconductor lasers

Tags: resource-recommendations, semiconductor-physics, laser

I have already some books about lasers, but none of them has an overview of many different laser types. At the same time while reading different papers, I have learned about existence of five various semiconductor laser types over two days. I cannot look for a specific article about specific type, everytime I see a new abbreviation.

I would love to have a book that contains an overview of as many types of semiconductor lasers as possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not really about physics.

Comment: @Gert there are literally two entire categories devoted to both LASERS and to RESOURCE RECOMMENTATIONS. My question is about a resource recommendation about lasers, I want to know physical mechanisms of various lasers. How much more physics do you need?

Comment: What do you mean by 'types' - compositions, physical layout, what?

Comment: @JonCuster I mean physical layout. E.g. DBR, DFB, Ring Resonator, Race Track, etc.

Comment: @Gert also what do you think this question is about if not physics?